# XSockets : Difference between ClientGuid and StorageGuid

Tags: c#, connection, xsockets.net

For each connection to the XSockets Server, the client has 2 ID's types:

1. **ClientGuid**
2. **StorageGuid**

What's the difference between them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clientguid is unique per connection and the storageguid will be stored in the browser between connections so that you can store data in memory on the server between connections for example